# Is there a way to set a variable's value to a TextView's text using XML in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am writing a little program for Android (I am a newbie to Java), and I wonder if there's a way to set a TextView-text's value to that of a `public static double` variable already defined in the corresponding .java file, only by using XML code, like I can do with `DynamicResource` in C#-XAML.

I have managed to programatically set the TextView's text by using

```
TextView value1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
value1.setText(String.valueOf(MyClass.staticVariableInMyClass));
```

But I would really like to do it, if possible, by editing the XML files of my project, as I do not need to update the TextView's text anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't access static properties into your classes ,but you can create [string resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ways to set text in TextView : XML - add attribute to TextView element `android:text="your text"` . Java:

`TextView tvId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
tvId.setText("your text");`

If you have double variable convert it like this. `String.valueof(double var);`